# Line break problems sending SMS through SMTP ftrom VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, smtp, sms, line, break

I wrote a VB.NET application to send notifications by SMS using an SMTP gateway (mobilenumber@mobileprovider.com).

The message includes line breaks and display well under most providers but not all.

For some providers, the message will display in one line with line breaks showing as "0D0A" which just won't work for me.

Is therea solution to this problem?

Using an SMS agregator is out of the question for my solution.

---

Yes, I did that. Turned out to be carrier specific.

Yet another problem i am having is specific to the phone model (one specific user receive the messages well on his old razor, changed to a new motorola phone with the same carrier and now receives an empty message).

Any ideas ?

Comment: With SMTP to SMS gateways you give up a lot of control over the display of the messages. There's no way around this.

Comment: There must be a way. I know of a similar system (Written in Java) that does the same thing without issues with the same mobile providers.

Comment: The problem isn't something you can control with code. Even if you came up with workarounds for all the major carriers, you'd still be at their mercy if they changed how they handled formatting. Even if you use a gateway you can't guarantee how messages look on the receiving end, though you do get a much more consistent experience.

Comment: I am not looking for fancy formatting. Just a regular line break

Answer (score 0):

This is neither vb.net or smtp problem.

It sure looks like it is mobile provider specific. Try checking your (mail message) encoding - have you tried pure ASCII?

If I'm not mistaken 0D0A is UTF-8 for line break...